# Using Jquery variable in php curl function

Tags: php, jquery, html

In short i have the below code :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryVariable(variable,def) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return def;
}
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = 'static/popups/'+getQueryVariable('event_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tv_id',0)+getQueryVariable('tid',0)+getQueryVariable('channel',0)+'.html';
} 
</script>
<body onload="redirect()">
<style>body{background-color: #000000; text-align: center;}</style>
</body></html>
```

`window.location.href` in the code above  will redirect to final URL i want to make it not to redirect instead use this final URL in new CUrl function to get its source code.

till now 3 hours and i cant figure it out .

the code i will use to get the final url source code is:

```
<?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "the final url";

    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    echo $html;
?>
```

how can i merge these to functions and integrate both?

Comment: Cant you change `window.location.href` to a var and use jquery to pass using `$.ajax` to a curl script that returns the src. Also FYI `get_data()` is never called, so your still using fgc

Comment: how to change window.location.href to a var then pass this var to the php script suggest me the code